# Remove old models from memory

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created simple example http://jsfiddle.net/n7tntcb5/

```
$ (function () {
'use strict';

var ButtonView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName : 'button',

    events : {
        'click' : 'onClick'
    },

    initialize : function (options) {
        this.collection = options.collection;
    },

    render : function () {
        this.$el.html ('Click');
        return this;
    },

    onClick : function (event) {
        this.collection.reset ([
            { "id" : _.random (0, 1000), data : new Array (100000).join ('a') },
            { "id" : _.random (0, 1000), data : new Array (100000).join ('a') },
            { "id" : _.random (0, 1000), data : new Array (100000).join ('a') }
        ]);
    }
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName : 'ul',

    initialize : function (options) {
        options || (options = {});

        this.views = [];
        this.collection = options.collection;

        this.listenTo (this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    empty : function () {
        _.each (this.views, function (view) {
            view.remove ();
        });

        this.$el.empty ();
    },

    render : function () {
        this.empty ();

        this.collection.each (function (model) {
            var view = new ListItemView ({ model : model });
            this.views.push (view);
            this.$el.append (view.render ().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

var ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName : 'li',

    initialize : function (options) {
        options || (options = {});

        this.model = options.model;
        this.collection = options.collection;

        this.listenTo (this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render : function () {
        this.$el.html (this.model.get ('id'));
        return this;
    },

    remove : function () {
        if (this.model) {
            //this.model.clear ();
            delete this.model;
        }
    }
});

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults : {
        id : null,
        name : '',
        data : ''
    }
});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model : Model,

    parse : function (response, options) {
        return response.models || response;
    }
});

var collection = new Collection ();
var list = new ListView ({ collection : collection });
var button = new ButtonView ({ collection : collection });

$ ('body')
    .append (list.render ().el)
    .append (button.render ().el);
});
```

In "Backbone Eye" Firefox plugin or Chrome's "Backbone Debugger" I see that number of models constantly grows with every button click. How can I free memory from old objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `empty` function doesn't clean everything up. Sure, you're calling `remove` on everything  in `this.views` but you never empty the `views` array. Try this version:

```
empty: function() {
    _.each(this.views, function(view) {
        console.log(view.cid)
        view.remove();
    });

    this.$el.empty();
}
```

and watch the console as you click the button a few times: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/27b15fsr/

Your `ListView` ends up with an ever growing array of `ListItemView` references in its `views` array and those zombie views will have references to the collection which will have references to the models. You need to plug this leak:

```
empty: function() {
    _.each(this.views, function(view) {
        view.remove();
    });
    this.$el.empty();
    this.views = [ ]; // <------
}
```

BTW, you don't need to do this in your view `initialize` methods:

```
this.collection = options.collection;
```

Backbone will deal with that by itself; from the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`, `attributes` and `events`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to empty this.views! Thanks You, mu, very much (-:

P. S. `this.collection = options.collection;` is just for clarity, thanks anyway (-: